# What is a noun for a person who is underrated despite being really good at something?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english, slang

I'm looking for a word (a noun) to describe a person who is really good at something but somehow underrated.

Comment: I've got to agree with @Kris that "underrated" is really the most obvious choice here. The two current answers (_unsung hero_ and _dark horse_) don't mean the same thing.

Comment: What do you call someone who asks something despite having a question?

Comment: Underrated isn't a noun.

Comment: Please give an example of the situation where you would use this word, and describe the research you have done so far. An explanation of how to write a "single word request"-type question can be found on the [tag information page](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Vaguely, might Cassandra fit that bill, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra of Troy? 

Otherwise, I bet you have to look a very long way… Aren't such people 'somehow underrated' precisely because no-one interested in their area of expertise, is interested in them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've always like the phrase [Unsung hero](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unsung-hero) for someone who's contribution is underrated/valued:

> **Unsung hero**: a person who makes a substantive yet unrecognized contribution; a person whose bravery is unknown or unacknowledged

Comment: Obligatory link to the [Unsung Hero](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) badge.

Comment: I think this answer is good, because it specifically implies the person has made important contributions.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "somehow" underrated, but I would refer to somebody like that as a [dark horse](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dark-horse)

> a person who keeps their interests and ideas secret, especially someone who has a surprising ability or skill:
>
> *Anna's such a dark horse - I had no idea she'd published a novel.*

It's marked as British English, so may not be known in the US.

Comment: The phrase is used in the US with similar, but not quite the same meaning, and I’ve usually heard it in particular contexts relating to a competition of some sort (most especially a political race, wherein you might have a *dark horse candidate*).